# Sagemaker Pre-processing/Training Jobs vs ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-sagemaker

We are considering using Sagemaker jobs/ECS as a resource for a few of our ML jobs. Our jobs are based on a custom docker file (no spark, just basic ML python libraries) and thus all that is required is resource for the container.

Wanted to know is there any specific advantage of using Sagemaker vs ECS here ? Also, As in our use-case we only require a resource for running docker image, would processing Job / training job serve the same purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you could make use of a either a Training Job or Processing Job (assuming the ML jobs are for transient training and/or processing).

The benefit of using SageMaker over ECS is that SageMaker manages the infrastructure. The Jobs are also transient and as such will be killed after training/processing while your artifacts will be automatically saved to S3.

With SageMaker Training or Processing Jobs all you need to do is bring your container (sitting in ECR) and kick off the Job with a single API ([CreateTrainingJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html), [CreateProcessingJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateProcessingJob.html))